# How do I set the location for the link in the title of a google reader subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-reader, atom-feed

I've got an atom feed in my application that's build using `atom_feed`, and it's working, except that when the feed is subscribed to in Google Reader, the link it uses for the title of the subscription is pointing to the wrong URL.

I tried specifying the root_url parameter as such:

```
atom_feed(:root_url => 'http://link.to/proper.page') do |f|
  ...
end
```

Which has changed the `href` value for the `<link type="text/html" rel="alternate" />` element generated, but the link in Reader stays the same. I cannot seem to find any help on this in the google reader documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:url` option should do it, not `:root_url`.

I am still surprised since it defaults to the current URL. I've never had to specify it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just an issue of google reader caching or something else, but from some of my feeds (I've got one per user) it's working after the change but for ones I viewed earlier it's still using the wrong link.